# parallel and sequential dotproduct programs different result

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, pthreads

I've wrote this two versions of code for computing a dotproduct operation on two arrays. each length is 256. here is very simple sequential code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    double sum;
    double a[256], b[256];
    int n = 256, i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = i * 0.5;
        b[i] = i * 2.0; 
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sum = sum + a[i]*b[i];
    }
    printf ("sum = %f\n", sum);
}//main
```

answer is `5559680`

but the parallel code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUMTHRDS 4

double sum;
double a[256], b[256];
int status;
int n=256;
pthread_t thds[NUMTHRDS];
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;

void* dotprod(void *arg){
    int myid, i, my_first, my_last;
    double sum_local;

    myid = (int)arg;
    my_first = myid * n/NUMTHRDS;
    my_last = (myid + 1) * n/NUMTHRDS;

    sum_local = 0;
    for (i=my_first; i<=my_last; i++){
        sum_local = sum_local + a[i]*b[i];
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
    sum = sum + sum_local;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);

    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}//dotprod

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = i * 0.5;
        b[i] = i * 2.0;
    }

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for (i=0; i<NUMTHRDS; i++){
        pthread_create(&thds[i], &attr, dotprod, (void*)i);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    for(i=0; i<NUMTHRDS; i++){
        pthread_join(thds[i], (void **)&status);
    }

    printf("sum = %f \n", sum);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexsum);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;   
}//main
```

answer is 5617024

i totally confused what is this difference for?

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=n; i++)` doesn't seem right...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - no it doesn't matter, because a[0] and b[0] are both equal to zero.

Comment: It does matter, because you're exceeding the array bounds.

Comment: The 1st example reads out of `a`'s and `b`'s bounds. I ran this under valgrind and it does not complain in any way? Why this?

Comment: @alk: Because Valgrind can only check dynamically-allocated memory.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Uhm yes, forgot about this. So `valgrind --tool=exp-sgcheck` might do the job. At least for this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

off by one error.

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++){

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

and

```
for (i=my_first; i<=my_last; i++){

for (i=my_first; i<my_last; i++){
```

In the first program, you are adding in a[256] and b[256], which is off the end of the array.
most likely those values were 0, so you got the right answer.

In the second program, you are counting some parts of the array twice: 64, 128, 192, and
still adding in index 256.

Always check the boundary conditions of your loops, especially with array accesses.